# SQL for preventing same photo/item from being re-tagged with the same tag

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If I have a table like so:

```
create table tagged_photos (
    id int auto_increment,
    photo_id int,
    tag_id int,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(photo_id) references photos(id) on delete cascade
);

+----+----------+--------+
| id | photo_id | tag_id |
+----+----------+--------+
|  2 |        2 |      3 |
|  3 |        3 |      5 |
|  4 |        4 |      7 |
|  5 |     NULL |     12 |
|  6 |     NULL |     13 |
|  7 |     NULL |     14 |
|  8 |       15 |     18 |
|  9 |       15 |     19 |
| 10 |       15 |     20 |
| 11 |       21 |     32 |
| 14 |        2 |     32 |
| 15 |        2 |     35 |
| 16 |        2 |     18 |
| 17 |        2 |     32 |
| 18 |        2 |     35 |
| 19 |        2 |     18 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

And the user decides to edit the photo and then save it with the same tags how can I prevent duplication as seen here?:

```
| 14 |        2 |     32 |
| 15 |        2 |     35 |
| 16 |        2 |     18 |
| 17 |        2 |     32 |
| 18 |        2 |     35 |
| 19 |        2 |     18 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Do you have control over Insert query  to amend ?

Comment: Yes ------>>>> @Sami

Comment: You can control through IF Exists clause in query, as mentioned in my answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table tagged_photos (
    id int auto_increment,
    photo_id int,
    tag_id int,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(photo_id) references photos(id) on delete cascade,
    unique key (photo_id, tag_id)
);
```

Comment: Does `unique_key(photo_id, tag_id)` ensure that both photo_id and tag_id must together as a whole be unique before inserting?

Comment: yes, unique key(col1, col2) will ensure that the pair is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not adding this as a comment, but I don't have enough (50) rep to post comments.

An alternative to the answer above is to create a unique index. You can use or the other, but there is not need to create both a unique key and a unique index.

After table creation, create the unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxtagged_photos on tagged_photos  (photo_id , tag_id);
```

The key is only a constraint, that those values cannot be repeated. The index has an added advantage of making lookups (select ... where) faster when the fields that compose the index are being used.

Comment: Actually, the unique index is what's used to *implement* the unique constraint.  When you create a unique constraint, the database automatically creates a unique index to check the constraint, so there's no performance advantage in creating a unique index directly.  But unique constraints are a standard SQL feature, whereas indexes are not, so you're better off using the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Update Insert query , if photo_id already exists then update, else Insert

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT  1  FROM tagged_photos  WHERE photo_id =  '2' ) 
   UPDATE tagged_photos  
      SET tag_id = 'NewTagNumber'
    WHERE photo_id = '2'
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO tagged_photos  (photo_id,tag_id)
    VALUES ('2', '35')
```

Comment: This is not a valid query, it would have to be in a stored procedure. Why not just use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me Barmar, I thought he access to query/stored procedure.